# Custom ListView in tabs

Tags: android, listview

I have a trouble whit making custom listview in two tab (on fragmets), I try the similar code, that I use for custom listView in Activity, but for tabs it doesnt work.
Tnx

Activity whit two tabs:

```
public class List_view_meni_mesni_meniji extends AppCompatActivity implements           
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_meni__mesni__meniji__izbran);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewByid(R.id.fab1);         

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(List_view_meni_mesni_meniji.this, MojKroznik.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs_mesni_meni);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("PONUDBE"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("PRILJUBLJENI"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_mesni_meni);
    final PagerAdapterMesniMeni adapter = new PagerAdapterMesniMeni(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    System.out.println("pritisnili smo back");
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}



//@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    System.out.println("tukaj sem");
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.meniji) {
        System.out.println("skocim na activity");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MeniMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.jedi) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,JediMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.pijaca) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,PijaceMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.akcije) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AkcijeMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.moj_krožnik){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MojKroznik.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.pomoc) {

    } else if (id == R.id.oNas)  {

    } else if(id == R.id.nastavitve) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true; 
    }
 }
```

fragment 1 (tab1) layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.approw.fastorder1.Fragment_Mesni_Meni_1">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_meni1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment 1 java code:

```
package com.example.approw.fastorder1;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Fragment_Mesni_Meni_1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,BundlesavedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__mesni__meni_1, container,  false);
   }

}
```

custom row layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/naslov_mesni_meni_1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/cena_mesni_meni_1"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your code - or at least the relevant part? I migrated my app from activities to fragments and I have a list view on the last tab that works.

Comment: I post a code for 1 tab (fragment)